# Partition an arc into portions as per the Quadrant in which that portion lies

Tags: algorithm, math

The problem seems very simple but I am not able to find an elegant solution for it.

I have an `arc` defined by

```
startAngle ( -360 <= startAngle <= 360 ), 
sweepAngle ( -360 <= sweepAngle <= 360 ) 
and a radius (not important here).
```

I want to divide this arc into pairs of `(startAngle1, sweepAngle1), ...` such that there is a different pair for each of the four quadrants.

```
Eg. If startAngle = 45, sweepAngle = 90, then there shall be two pairs (45,45) and (90,45).
```

A brute-force way is to check for all `4^2` possibilities (each of `startAngle` and corresponding `endAngle` (calculated by `sweepAngle`) can be in any of the 4 quadrants).

But I think an elegant simpler solution should be there. I just can't seem to find it.

Thanks.

EDIT:
One algorithm I just thought of is:
1. Starting from startAngle, I iterate towards the sweepAngle and keep checking whether I encounter any quadrant boundary (mod(theta) = 0, 90, 180, 270, 360).
2. Update to the list of arcs accordingly.

Anything better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would start with `90-startAngle%90`, the modulo operator gives you the part which is `startAngle` in it's current quadrant. 90 minus that value is the part that the startAngle has to go in this quadrant. So, that is your first sweep angle. Now you can add always 90 to your next sweep angle. You do this until your calculated current `sweepAngle` is larger than your input `sweepAngle`. Then you know that you are in the last quadrant. In pseudo-code, `out` prints a new pair of angles:

```
currentPosition=startAngle
currentSweep = 90-startAngle%90
totalAngle=0
while (currentSweep < sweepAngle)
    out (currentPosition, currentSweep)
    currentPosition += currentSweep
    totalAngle += currentSweep
    currentSweep += 90;
out (currentPosition, sweepAngle-totalAngle)
```

Probably you have to look into the corner cases more closely, what happens when startAngle is exactly 90, e.g. But basically this should be the algorithm with a reasonable running time (and elegance, imo).

Comment: Thanks, implemented my algorithm on similar lines.